# Dropdown list loses value on gridview RowCommand

Tags: asp.net, gridview, postback, drop-down-menu

I have a `DropDownList` in a `GridView`. I am filling the `GridView` dynamically in `GridView RowCreated()`. I want to get that `DropDownList`'s value when I click the `GridView`'s Command Button.

In the `RowCommand` function, I am trying to get the value. However, I can't find the control in that function. Surprisingly, another `DropDownList` works fine in the same function.

C# code follows:

```
if (Request.Params["ID"] != null && Request.Params["ID"] != "")
{
    FirmID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Params["ID"]);
    //OfficeList = IFARecord.GetOffices(FirmID);    
}
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    GV_SABAdvisers.DataSourceID = "objectDataSourceSAV";
    GV_SABAdvisers.DataBind();
}

protected void GV_SABAdvisers_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Index")
    {
        int Index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow row = GV_SABAdvisers.Rows[Index];

        //Not working
        DropDownList Offices = row.FindControl("ddlLocation") as DropDownList;
        String officeID = (Offices is DropDownList) ? Offices.SelectedValue : null;

        DropDownList ddlJobTitle = row.FindControl("ddlJobTitle") as DropDownList;

        if (ddlJobTitle is DropDownList)
        {
            newAdviserJobTitle.JobTitleID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlJobTitle.SelectedValue);// this works fine.
        }
    }
}    

protected void GV_SABAdvisers_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList ddlLocation = e.Row.FindControl("ddlLocation") as DropDownList;
        DropDownList ddlJobTitle = e.Row.FindControl("ddlJobTitle") as DropDownList;   
        DataTable OfficeList = GetOffices(FirmID);
        DataTable dtJob = MyTouchstone.Advisers.AdviserFirmJobTitle.AllJobTitle();

        foreach (DataRow aOffice in OfficeList.Rows)
        {
            ddlLocation.Items.Add(new ListItem(aOffice["Address1"].ToString() + ", " + aOffice["Postcode"].ToString(), aOffice["OfficeID"].ToString()));
        }

        foreach (DataRow aJob in dtJob.Rows)
        {
            ddlJobTitle.Items.Add(new ListItem(aJob["JobTitle"].ToString(), aJob["JobTitleID"].ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

ASP markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="True">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GV_SABAdvisers" AutoGenerateColumns="false" PageSize = "10"
            CssClass="cssPager" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true"
            OnPageIndexChanging="GV_SABAdvisers_PageIndexChanging"  
            runat="server" onrowcommand="GV_SABAdvisers_RowCommand" 
            onrowcreated="GV_SABAdvisers_RowCreated">
            <PagerStyle />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Job Title">
                    <ItemStyle Width="80px" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlJobTitle" Width="80px" runat="Server"></asp:DropDownList>  
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location">
                    <ItemStyle Width="200px" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLocation" Width="80px" runat="Server"></asp:DropDownList>  
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Please provide your ASP.NET markup - I would focus on the differences in the markup around ddlLocation versus ddlJobTitle, since one works and one does not.

Comment: In `RowCreated` event handler you access `ddlLocation` without call to `e.Row.FindControl` method. Does it placed in GridView?

Comment: Plz see the Asp markup now. both control is the same. and I am binding data only once.

Comment: hi Yuriy, ddlLocation is also taking e.Row.FindControl to access. I modify the code. i miss that to submit in the post. i modify the code again. thanks

Comment: Copy-paste here full code of `RowCommand` event handler also. Where from you get `row` object?

Comment: hi @yuriy, I am getting row from "GridViewRowEventArgs e". it is perameter of GridViewRowEventArgs.

Comment: But how you get row in `RowCommand` event since it has second argument of type `GridViewCommandEventArgs`?

Comment: Hi Yuriy, sorry for part code submission. I submit the code now to get row.

Comment: HI all, Thank for help. I have solved the problem. I just bind data in RowDataBound event instead of RowCreated Event. I don't know why in RowCreated function, that dropdown is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where have you used the CommandName "Index" in your source code.